# Concisely, robustly, temporarily stashing c++ iostream formats

Tags: c++, c++17, stream, raii

I got tired of the boilerplate and tedium restoring formatting context, so I made an RAII stasher that relies on the destroy-at-end-of-full-statement temporary semantics. With C++17 I can get it down to a single type, no helpers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template< template<typename, class> class streamtmp, typename charT, class traits >
struct fmtstash {
    typedef streamtmp<charT,traits> streamtype;
    streamtype &from;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flags;
    std::streamsize width;
    std::streamsize precision;
    charT fill;
    fmtstash(streamtype &str)
        : from(str), flags(str.flags()), width(str.width())
        , precision(str.precision()), fill(str.fill())  {}
    ~fmtstash() { from.flags(flags), from.width(width), from.precision(precision), from.fill(fill); }
    template<typename T> streamtype  &operator<<(const T &rhs) { return from << rhs; }
    template<typename T> streamtype  &operator>>(      T &rhs) { return from >> rhs; }
};

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    using namespace std;
    fmtstash(cout) << hex << 51901 <<'\n';
    cout << 51901 <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

which produces about the easiest-to-write-and-read formatting I can manage.

Am I missing any bets here? Shorter or more robust is what I'm after.

The biggest improvement I found since I first wrote it is to use `from << rhs` instead of the `from.operator<<(rhs)` I had, since user-defined stream insert/extractors have to be free functions and of course an explicit member callout breaks those.

I could make the template args simpler, just `template<class streamtmp>`, the full breakout is a holdover from when I had the internal reference as `ios_base<charT,traits> &from;` instead of the full original type, but I ran across a broken inserter that wanted to be first or only and took an ostream reference as its left operand.

And of course the boost savers don't supply the inserter and extractor templates at all.  Is this an oversight or is there some argument against using the destroy-at-end-of-full-expression semantics this way?

Comment: I posted [something similar](/q/189753/75307) a couple of years ago, so you might want to compare approaches.  I do like the simple usability of your code; I wish I'd thought of making it usable as a stream itself.

Comment: @TobySpeight I missed yours in searching for dups (iostream vs stream, my bad), so I missed all the great comments and discussion there.  Locales and afaics never locally changed, and changing them seems so expensive, I left them out.  Also seems I should be using && not &, to get the value-or-ref deduction working.

Answer (score 3):

One tiny improvement I'd suggest is that the stored state can all be declared `const`:

```
const std::ios_base::fmtflags flags;
const std::streamsize width;
const std::streamsize precision;
const charT fill;
```

There are no implications for assignability of `fmtstash` objects, as we already had a reference member.

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't using the full template form of the stream, just drop it.  `charT` can be replaced by `stream::char_type`.

There is an rvalue overload for standard stream types.

The parameters to `main` are conventionally named `argc` and `argv`.  Since you aren't using these parameters, omit them to avoid unused parameter warnings.

I think the code may be more readable if you avoid squeezing everything on one line:

```
~fmtstash()
{
    from.flags(flags);
    from.width(width);
    from.precision(precision);
    from.fill(fill);
}
```

instead of

```
~fmtstash() { from.flags(flags), from.width(width), from.precision(precision), from.fill(fill); }
```

Similarly,

```
template <typename T>
streamtype& operator<<(const T& rhs)
{
    return form << rhs;
}
```

instead of

```
template<typename T> streamtype  &operator<<(const T &rhs) { return from << rhs; }
```

> And of course the boost savers don't supply the inserter and extractor
>   templates at all. Is this an oversight or is there some argument
>   against using the destroy-at-end-of-full-expression semantics this
>   way?

Probably because the "destroy-at-end-of-full-expression semantics" is not very useful — boost savers work with scopes, which allow for more flexible state saving.  If you really want the full expression semantics, you can do it like this:

```
boost::io::ios_flags_saver(std::cout),
std::cout << std::hex << 51901 <<'\n';
```